# method splice () et findindex () javascript problem search board

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

my problem is that I have an array named object of several objects which are themselves in an array.
How to retrieve them with the splice and findindex method?
For the moment with my current code it removes the last object from the array when I click on any which button deleted from the basket.
I have another object2 which is a simple array containing only the id's and the method to use works very well .
I want to delete an object from the object array by searching by the id.
With exemple object2 array ,the method works very well in my code, but not with the object array please help me for this.

object :

```
(5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
0: {lenses: Array(2), _id: "5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061", name: "Zurss 50S", price: 49900, description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin…mpor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", …}
1: "35mm 1.4"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
1: (2) [{…}, "50mm 1.8"]
2: (2) [{…}, "25mm 4.5"]
3: (2) [{…}, "50mm 1.7"]
4: (2) [{…}, "50mm 1.4"]
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)

object2 :

(5) ["5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061", "5be1ef211c9d44000030b062", "5be9bc241c9d440000a730e7", "5be9c4471c9d440000a730e8", "5be9c4c71c9d440000a730e9"]
```

here is my code

```
butonAll[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        console.log("supprime moi");
        const id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");

        objectJs2.splice(
          objectJs2.findIndex((x) => {
            return x === id;
          }),
          1
        );
        objectJs.splice(
          objectJs.findIndex((x) => {
            return x === id;
          }),
          1
        );
        localStorage.setItem("object", JSON.stringify(objectJs));
        localStorage.setItem("id", JSON.stringify(objectJs2));
        console.log(id);
        console.log(objectJs.length);
        console.log(line2);
        //location.href = "panier.html";
        if (objectJs.length === 0) {
          localStorage.removeItem("object");
          localStorage.removeItem("id");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Please add interpunction to your sentences. It's very hard to read what your issue is.

Comment: What is your `object array` ?

Comment: my array object is notify at the top in my post just before array object2 and my code and below

Comment: the object array contains 5 array containing themselves 2 arrays and the id is in these last arrays

Answer (score 0):

#### Update the findIndex function to look inside the array and then at the property

From what I can understand, the inner array always consists of two elements: first an object which has a property "id", and then a string.

Based on this, I think you should be able to find the id by replacing `return x === id` with `x[0].id === id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
objectJs2.splice(
      objectJs2.findIndex((x) => {
        return x === id;
      }),
      1
    );
    objectJs.splice(
      objectJs.findIndex((x) => {
        return x[0]._id === id;
      }),
      1
    );
    objectJs.splice(
      objectJs.findIndex((x) => {
        return x[1] === lense;
      }),
      1
    );
```

this on top no works supprim 2 product it s very bad

```
butonAll[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log("supprime moi");
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
    const lense = e.target.getAttribute("data-lenses");

    objectJs2.splice(
      objectJs2.findIndex((x) => {
        return x === id;
      }),
      1
    );
    objectJs.splice(
      objectJs.findIndex((x) => {
        return x[0]._id === id && X[1] === lense;
      }),
      1
    );
```

but on the top this is solution works very well

the method x [0] ._ id works very well thank you for the answer. but there was a small problem which to continue on the basket, it is the fact that if 2 objects have the same id but that their lenses are not there even it removes the last object as in the situation of my first post. I added a data-lenses attribute to the deleted button and try to add the method, if I do 2 splices on object it removes 2 product for me so the solution is to make a single splice object and a return x [0] ._ id = == id && x [1] === lense. It works
here is my new code on top